# Extract date from multiple webpages with Python

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, data-extraction

I want to extract date when news article was published on websites. For some websites I have exact html element where date/time is (div, p, time) but on some websites I do not have:

These are the links for some websites (german websites):

(3 Nov 2020)
http://www.linden.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/?action=showinfo&info_id=1074226

(Dec. 1, 2020) http://www.reutigen.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/welcome.php?action=showinfo&info_id=1066837&ls=0&sq=&kategorie_id=&date_from=&date_to=

(10/22/2020) http://buchholterberg.ch/de/Gemeinde/Information/News/Newsmeldung?filterCategory=22&newsid=905

I have tried 3 different solutions with Python libs such as `requests`, `htmldate` and `date_guesser` but I'm always getting None, or in case of `htmldate` lib, I always get same date (2020.1.1)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from htmldate import find_date
from date_guesser import guess_date, Accuracy

# Lib find_date
url = "http://www.linden.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/?action=showinfo&info_id=1074226"
response = requests.get(url)
my_date = find_date(response.content, extensive_search=True)
print(my_date, '\n')


# Lib guess_date
url = "http://www.linden.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/?action=showinfo&info_id=1074226"
my_date = guess_date(url=url, html=requests.get(url).text)
print(my_date.date, '\n')


# Lib Requests # I DO NOT GET last modified TAG
my_date = requests.head('http://www.linden.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/?action=showinfo&info_id=1074226')
print(my_date.headers, '\n')
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Can you please tell me is there a way to extract date of publication from websites like this (where I do not have specific divs, p, and datetime elements).

IMPORTANT!
I want to make universal date extraction, so that I can put these links in for loop and run the same function to them.

Comment: What do you mean by universal date extraction?

Comment: to extract  date from some news article text, but to write script for that that will work the same on all websites

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any module that can do universal date extraction from websites in foreign languages.  The all urls section of my answer can be easily modified to extract date from any website.   Some of the items within that answer can be moved to a function or even a class with some additional effort.

Comment: I believe that I addressed this problem "extract date when news article was published on websites" with my answer.  If you are still having some issues please let me know and I will look at some additional sites.

Comment: your solution works for those 3 websites, im looking for solution that will work on every website. Im looking for some kind of lib that will detect dates, in any format

Comment: I'm 100% sure that there IS NOT a single solution that works for every website.  You will need to use several methods to extract the date strings from multiple website that use different formats and languages.  Like I previously stated you can modified my code to work with any website with little effort.

Comment: can you see the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225534/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-taga).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never had much success with some of the date parsing libraries, so I usually go another route.  I believe that the best method to extract the date strings from these sites in your question is with regular expressions.

***website: linden.ch***

```
import requests
import re as regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

url = "http://www.linden.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/?action=showinfo&info_id=1074226"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
page_body = soup.find('body')
find_date = regex.search(r'(Datum der Neuigkeit)\s(\d{1,2}\W\s\w+\W\s\d{4})', str(page_body))
reformatted_timestamp = datetime.strptime(find_date.groups()[1], '%d. %b. %Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print(reformatted_timestamp)
# print output 
03-11-2020
```

***website: buchholterberg.ch***

```
import requests
import re as regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

url = "http://buchholterberg.ch/de/Gemeinde/Information/News/Newsmeldung?filterCategory=22&newsid=905"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
page_body = soup.find('body')
find_date = regex.search(r'(Veröffentlicht)\s\w+:\s(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\s(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4})', str(page_body))
reformatted_timestamp = datetime.strptime(find_date.groups()[2], '%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print(reformatted_timestamp)
# print output
22-10-2020
```

### Update 12-04-2020

I looked at the source code for the two Python libraries: *htmldate* and date_guesser that you mentioned. Neither of these libraries can currently extract the date from the 3 sources that you listed in your question. The primary reason for this lack of extraction is linked to the date formats and language (german) of these target sites.

I had some free time so I put this together for you. The answer below can easily be modified to extract from any website and can be refined as needed based on the format of your target sources.   It currently extract from all the links contained in URLs.

---

***all urls***

```
import requests
import re as regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_date(can_of_soup):
   page_body = can_of_soup.find('body')
   clean_body = ''.join(str(page_body).replace('\n', ''))
   if 'Datum der Neuigkeit' in clean_body or 'Veröffentlicht' in clean_body:
     date_formats = '(Datum der Neuigkeit)\s(\d{1,2}\W\s\w+\W\s\d{4})|(Veröffentlicht am: \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4})'
     find_date = regex.search(date_formats, clean_body, regex.IGNORECASE)
     if find_date:
        clean_tuples = [i for i in list(find_date.groups()) if i]
        return ''.join(clean_tuples[1])
   else:
       tags = ['extra', 'elementStandard elementText', 'icms-block icms-information-date icms-text-gemeinde-color']
       for tag in tags:
          date_tag = page_body.find('div', {'class': f'{tag}'})
          if date_tag is not None:
            children = date_tag.findChildren()
            if children:
                find_date = regex.search(r'(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4})', str(children))
                return ''.join(find_date.groups())
            else:
                return ''.join(date_tag.contents)


def get_soup(target_url):
   response = requests.get(target_url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
   return soup


urls = {'http://www.linden.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/?action=showinfo&info_id=1074226',
    'http://www.reutigen.ch/de/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/welcome.php?action=showinfo&info_id=1066837&ls=0'
    '&sq=&kategorie_id=&date_from=&date_to=',
    'http://buchholterberg.ch/de/Gemeinde/Information/News/Newsmeldung?filterCategory=22&newsid=905',
    'https://www.steffisburg.ch/de/aktuelles/meldungen/Hochwasserschutz-und-Laengsvernetzung-Zulg.php',
    'https://www.wallisellen.ch/aktuellesinformationen/924227',
    'http://www.winkel.ch/de/aktuellesre/aktuelles/aktuellesinformationen/welcome.php?action=showinfo&info_id'
    '=1093910&ls=0&sq=&kategorie_id=&date_from=&date_to=',
    'https://www.aeschi.ch/de/aktuelles/mitteilungen/artikel/?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=87&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&cHash=ab4d329e2f1529d6e3343094b416baed'}


for url in urls:
   html = get_soup(url)
   article_date = extract_date(html)
   print(article_date)
```