# Confusing day and month when parsing dates in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to parse date each time the same way. I wrote a code that detects date in string, but it parses the date differently. My date is 3rd of November 2020, and it mixes the days and months:

```
import datefinder
import time
sample_dates = ["this is my sample date 2020.11.03 yes yes",
                "this is my sample date 2020-11-03 yes yes",
                "this is my sample date 2020/11/03 yes yes",
                "this is my sample date 03.11.2020 yes yes",
                "this is my sample date 03.11.2020 yes yes",
                "this is my sample date 03/11/2020 yes yes"]

for sample in sample_dates:
     matches = datefinder.find_dates(sample)
     matches = list(matches)
     print(matches)
     print(matches[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
     print()
```

How can I fix this?
I want to parse date each time the same way, regardless of the format in string.
can you show me how can I do that (i do not care what lib should i use)?

Comment: If your data is really mixed like that, you'll just have to get used to having incorrect dates.  There's no algorithmic way of knowing if the month or the day comes first.

Comment: If you don't know what comes first, you can only hope that one of the values is above 12, that's your day position - and you'll have to assume that the other dates are formatted the same.

Comment: well I always have situation where it is year-month-day od day-month-year. So month is always in the middle

Comment: If this question is related to your "Extract date from multiple webpages with Python" then it is easy to fix with some additional code.  I can post that code to this question.

Comment: @taga did the answer below help you solve your date format issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As I previously stated in your other question about extracting dates, there is ***no universal date extraction*** that can handle every date/time format.  Date cleaning in your case will require a multi-pronged approach, which I have outlined in the examples below:*

---

### Updated 12-06-2020

I'm going to assume that some of the dates within sample_dates are from the German language websites that you're scraping.  So this code below can parse those dates.

Please review the parameters for [dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse).

```
import datefinder
import re as regex
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser as dparser

sample_dates = ["this is my sample date 2020.11.03 yes yes",
            "this is my sample date 2020-11-03 yes yes",
            "this is my sample date 2020/11/03 yes yes",
            "this is my sample date 03.11.2020 yes yes",
            "this is my sample date 03.11.2020 yes yes",
            "this is my sample date 03/11/2020 yes yes"]

for sample in sample_dates:
  check_year_first = regex.search(r'\d{4}\W\d{1,2}\W\d{1,2}', sample)
  if check_year_first:
    date_strings = datefinder.find_dates(sample)
    for date_string in date_strings:
        reformatted_date = datetime.strptime(str(date_string), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print(reformatted_date)
  else:
     date_strings = datefinder.find_dates(sample, source=True)
     for date_string in date_strings:
        reformatted_date = dparser.parse(str(date_string[1]).replace('date', ''), dayfirst=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print(reformatted_date)
```

I'm also going to assume that the dates in this question are being produced from the output of your question [Extract date from multiple webpages with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095206/extract-date-from-multiple-webpages-with-python/65129998#65129998). If that is correct then add this code to the other code that I provided for that question. Like I stated before my other code can be modified to fit your data extraction and cleaning requirements.

```
import dateparser
from datetime import datetime

def reformatted_dates(date_string):
   # date format 3. Nov. 2020
   date_format_01 = regex.search(r'\d{1,2}\W\s\w+\W\s\d{4}', date_string)
   # date format 3. Dezember 2020
   date_format_02 = regex.search(r'\d{1,2}\W\s\w+\s\d{4}', date_string)
   if date_format_01:
     reformatted_date = dateparser.parse(date_string).strftime('%m.%d.%Y')
     return reformatted_date
   elif date_format_02:
      pass
      reformatted_date = dateparser.parse(date_string).strftime('%m.%d.%Y')
      return reformatted_date
   else:
       # date format 18.11.2020
       reformatted_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
       return reformatted_date
```